# My dropdown menu isn't showing below parent

Tags: html, css, dropdown

I'm creating a dropdown login form, but once the jQuery is working right, I get the menu displayed at left (when Log in is at right). Some images to see it clearly:

[image: 1]]

And when I click on 'Log in':

[image]

It loads this way. Here's the code:

HTML:

```html
<div id="navthing">
  <h2><a href="#" id="loginform">Log in</a> | <a href="#">Sign Up</a></h2>
  <div class="login">
    <div class="arrow-up"></div>
    <div class="formholder">
      <div class="randompad">
        <fieldset>
          <label name="email">Email</label>
          <input type="email" value="example@example.com" />
          <label name="password">Password</label>
          <input type="password" />
          <input type="submit" value="Login" />
        </fieldset>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```css
#navthing {
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.login {
  position: absolute;
  width:250px;
  display:none;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.formholder {
  background: #ecf0f1;
  width: 250px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  z-index: 1;
  display:block;
}

.arrow-up {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid #ECF0F1;
  left: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
}

.formholder input[type="email"], .formholder input[type="password"] {
  padding: 7px 5px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 96%;
  display: block;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s linear;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s linear;
  -o-transition: 0.3s linear;
  transition: 0.3s linear;
}

.formholder input[type="email"]:focus, .formholder input[type="password"]:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #1abc9c;
}
.formholder input[type="submit"] {
  background: #1abc9c;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.formholder input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #1bc6a4;
}

.randompad {
  padding: 10px;
}

.green {
  color: #1abc9c;
}

a {
  color: #ecf0f1;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  color: #1abc9c;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gx35L38z/)

I got the `.login`'s `position` in `absolute` because if not the menu made the `darkblue` div bigger. How could I display the menu (the arrow and the rest of the form) below 'log in'? I'm trying but with no result. Thank you.

Comment: can you make fiddle ?

Comment: please give full code or make snippet of it.

Comment: It is shown here: https://jsfiddle.net/gx35L38z/

Comment: The z-index thing was just a try and it is still there, but it doesn't make changes on code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this block to be in `absolute` position `relative` to this link, you have a couple of choices.

One, you keep this structure and put a relative position to the parent, `header` and then you position it.

Or you put this block in the container of the link itself and add a `position:relative;` to the container of the link.

I choose the first way to do it and [here is the JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gx35L38z/4/)

The code that change :

```
.login {
    position: absolute;
    width:250px;
    display:none;
    z-index: 9999;
  right: 50px;
  top:40px
}
.arrow-up {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid #ECF0F1;
  right: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
}
header {
    width:90%;
    height:30%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:darkblue;
    color:white;
    /*text-align:center;*/
    z-index: 8;
    position:relative; /* I add this line to make it works */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I correctly understand your question, you are trying to position your menu at the right side of navbar. If so, you just need to add correct position to it, by `right` or `left` properties. I've also change arrow position and add `position:relative` to your `#navthing`.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

$('input[type="submit"]').mousedown(function(){
  $(this).css('background', '#2ecc71');
});
$('input[type="submit"]').mouseup(function(){
  $(this).css('background', '#1abc9c');
});

$('#loginform').click(function(){
  $('.login').fadeToggle('slow');
  $(this).toggleClass('green');
});



$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var container = $(".login");

    if (!container.is(e.target) 
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) 
    {
        container.hide();
        $('#loginform').removeClass('green');
    }
});
});
```

```css
* {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, Tahoma;
 font-size: 62.5%;
 background: #242c38;
}

#navthing {
 text-align: right;
    position:relative;
 padding: 0.5em;
}

.login {
 position: absolute;
    right: 52px;
    top: 41px;
 width:250px;
 display:none;
 z-index: 9999;
}

.formholder {
  background: #ecf0f1;
  width: 250px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  z-index: 1;
  display:block;
}

.arrow-up {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid #ECF0F1;
  right: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
}

.formholder input[type="email"], .formholder input[type="password"] {
  padding: 7px 5px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 96%;
  display: block;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s linear;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s linear;
  -o-transition: 0.3s linear;
  transition: 0.3s linear;
}

.formholder input[type="email"]:focus, .formholder input[type="password"]:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #1abc9c;
}
.formholder input[type="submit"] {
  background: #1abc9c;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.formholder input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #1bc6a4;
}

.randompad {
  padding: 10px;
}

.green {
  color: #1abc9c;
}

a {
  color: #ecf0f1;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  color: #1abc9c;
}

header {
 width:90%;
 height:30%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background-color:darkblue;
 color:white;
 /*text-align:center;*/
 z-index: 8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
<div id="navthing">
      <h2><a href="#" id="loginform">Log in</a> | <a href="#">Sign Up</a></h2>
   <div class="login">
    <div class="arrow-up"></div>
     <div class="formholder">
       <div class="randompad">
           <fieldset>
             <label name="email">Email</label>
             <input type="email" value="example@example.com" />
             <label name="password">Password</label>
             <input type="password" />
             <input type="submit" value="Login" />
           </fieldset>
       </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do You want like this?

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

$('input[type="submit"]').mousedown(function(){
  $(this).css('background', '#2ecc71');
});
$('input[type="submit"]').mouseup(function(){
  $(this).css('background', '#1abc9c');
});

$('#loginform').click(function(){
  $('.login').fadeToggle('slow');
  $(this).toggleClass('green');
});



$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var container = $(".login");

    if (!container.is(e.target) 
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) 
    {
        container.hide();
        $('#loginform').removeClass('green');
    }
});
});
```

```css
* {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, Tahoma;
 font-size: 62.5%;
 background: #242c38;
}

#navthing {
 text-align: right;
 padding: 0.5em;
}

.login {
 position: absolute;
 width:250px;
 display:none;
 z-index: 9999;
    right:40px;
}

.formholder {
  background: #ecf0f1;
  width: 250px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  z-index: 1;
  display:block;
  margin-top:15px;
}

.arrow-up {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid #ECF0F1;
  left: 41%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}

.formholder input[type="email"], .formholder input[type="password"] {
  padding: 7px 5px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 96%;
  display: block;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s linear;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s linear;
  -o-transition: 0.3s linear;
  transition: 0.3s linear;
}

.formholder input[type="email"]:focus, .formholder input[type="password"]:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #1abc9c;
}
.formholder input[type="submit"] {
  background: #1abc9c;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.formholder input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #1bc6a4;
}

.randompad {
  padding: 10px;
}

.green {
  color: #1abc9c;
}

a {
  color: #ecf0f1;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  color: #1abc9c;
}

header {
 width:90%;
 height:30%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background-color:darkblue;
 color:white;
 /*text-align:center;*/
 z-index: 8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
<div id="navthing">
      <h2><a href="#" id="loginform">Log in</a> | <a href="#">Sign Up</a></h2>
   <div class="login">
    <div class="arrow-up"></div>
     <div class="formholder">
       <div class="randompad">
           <fieldset>
             <label name="email">Email</label>
             <input type="email" value="example@example.com" />
             <label name="password">Password</label>
             <input type="password" />
             <input type="submit" value="Login" />
           </fieldset>
       </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.login {
    position: absolute;
    width:250px;
    display:none;
    z-index: 9999;
  right: 50px;
  top: 40px;
}

.arrow-up {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid #ECF0F1;
  right: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
}
```